# Dagger 2: matching key exists in subcomponent

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to use dagger 2 for dependency injection in Kotlin. The dependency graph i'm trying to create is

`Application-> Activity -> Fragment`
with each component provided with the necessary bindings/providers. Here's my current structure:

**AppModule.kt**

```
@dagger.Module 
abstract class AppModule {

@Binds
abstract fun bindContext(application: Application): Context

@Binds
abstract fun bindApplication(application : Application) : Application
}
```

**AppComponent.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, 
AndroidInjectionModule::class, 
ActivityBuilder::class))
interface AppComponent : 
AndroidInjector<FreedomGuardianApp> {

@Component.Builder
abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<FreedomGuardianApp>()
}
```

**ActivityModule.kt**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

@PerActivity
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(MainActivityModule::class))
abstract fun bindMainActivity() : MainActivity
}
```

**MainActivityModule.kt**

```
@Module(includes = 
arrayOf(WatchFaceFragmentModule::class))
class MainActivityModule {

@Provides
fun adapter(activity: MainActivity): MyPagesAdapter {
    return MyPagesAdapter(activity.supportFragmentManager)
}
}
```

**WatchFaceFragmentModule.kt**

```
@Module
abstract class WatchFaceFragmentModule {

@PerFragment
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun contributeWatchFaceFragment(): WatchFaceFragment
}
```

**WatchFaceProvidersModule.kt**

```
@Module
class WatchFaceProvidersModule {
@Provides
fun gestureDetector(fragment: WatchFaceFragment): GestureDetectorCompat {
    return GestureDetectorCompat(fragment.context, fragment)
}

@Provides
@Named("textToSpeak")
fun textToSpeak(fragment: WatchFaceFragment): String {
    return fragment.resources.getString(R.string.time_string)
}

@Provides
fun textToSpeech(fragment: WatchFaceFragment): TextToSpeech {
    return TextToSpeech(fragment.context, fragment)
}
}
```

I'm injecting GestureDetectorCompat, String(textToSpeak), TextToSpeak in WatchFaceFragment.

Here's the error:

```
    public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.medicalguardian.freedomguardian.FreedomGuardianApp> {
                ^
  A binding with matching key exists in component: com.medicalguardian.freedomguardian.di.WatchFaceFragmentModule_ContributeWatchFaceFragment.WatchFaceFragmentSubcomponent
      com.medicalguardian.freedomguardian.ui.fragment.WatchFaceFragment is injected at
          com.medicalguardian.freedomguardian.ui.MainActivity.watchFaceFragment
      com.medicalguardian.freedomguardian.ui.MainActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.medicalguardian.freedomguardian.di.AppComponent ? com.medicalguardian.freedomguardian.di.ActivityBuilder_BindMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent]
```

Is my structure wrong? I'm not injecting in the constructor of WatchFaceFragment as it doesn't help. I'm using dagger support as well(DaggerFragment, DaggerApplication etc). If i'm not injecting the fragment but inject just the MainActivity, is works fine. How do i solve this issue? Apologize in advance for the lengthy read. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's no clean way around this. Your Fragment gets created _later_ in a SubComponent of your ActivityComponent, yet you try to access it at creation time of the Activity. You can't directly inject objects from a lower scope.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us where you're including WatchFaceProvidersModule, but it *should* be included on your `@ContributesAndroidInjector` annotation in WatchFaceFragmentModule.kt, and not in AppComponent or ActivityModule:

```
@Module
abstract class WatchFaceFragmentModule {

  @PerFragment
  @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(WatchFaceProvidersModule::class))
  abstract fun contributeWatchFaceFragment(): WatchFaceFragment
}
```

This should ensure that when injecting WatchFaceFragment (and the GestureCompat etc it requires) you have access to a WatchFaceFragment instance. Otherwise, as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1837367/david-medenjak) alluded to in the comments, the injector for your FreedomGuardianApp or MainActivity won't know which WatchFaceFragment to return; one may not exist yet.

Comment: Hi Jeff. This would introduce a cyclic dependency on WatchFaceFragment. Note that I'm injecting the fragment in MainActivity. I'm just trying to get the right structure I should follow.

Comment: @brainfreak The intention is that the Fragment should inject itself using `AndroidInjection.inject(this);` in `onAttach`, which creates an instance of your WatchFaceFragmentModule_ContributeWatchFaceFragment.WatchFaceFragmentSubcomponent per instance of your WatchFaceFragment.